# Added Logback to Tomcat, got java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, tomcat8

I am running Tomcat on Windows as a service. I added the following libraries to the Tomcat classpath:

- logback-core-1.1.3.jar
- logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
- logback-access-1.1.3.jar
- jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar
- c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar
- mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar

by using the `Configure Tomcat` tray application under the tab `Java/Java Classpath`. On one machine, everything works fine (Tomcat and application logs are recorded as I'd like them to). On another machine, I get:

```
`SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement 
Begin event threw error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle`
```

The exact classpath is:

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\logback-core-1.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib2\logback-access-1.1.3.jar;D:\logs

P.S. The motivation for what I've done is to get all of the logging output for a given server into a database. My application server only runs a single application, so setting up logging globally makes sense (especially since there are lots of ClassLoader-related issues with trying to keep logging separate between Tomcat and the application).

Part of the problem seems to be the way Tomcat's classpath is configured on Windows. I can't find good documentation on it. Maybe I should be setting the classpath elsewhere, like in `catalina.properties`?

Comment: I am getting the same thing.  I followed the examples: http://logback.qos.ch/access.html   and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html.  But I get this Error.  The file is located in catalina.jar which is passed used in the startup.sh script AND is supposed to be picked up in catalina.properties under the common.loader.  So, I am not sure how Tomcat is missing this class?

Comment: Just figured out that there is some problem with adding <Valve className="ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve"/> to the server.xml file.  Haven't dug into it, but if you have this in server.xml and remove it, you will no longer get the NoClassDefinition error.  Not sure if this is a logback issue or a tomcat issue.